# Как исправить программу, чтобы она выводила простые числа числа в порядке убывания?

Tags: python

```
def prost(n):
    for i in range(2,n//2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return 0
    return 1
x = [x for x in range(10,31)]
y = [y for y in range(10,31) if prost(y) == 1]
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: Хм.. А может, range умеет в обратном порядке итерироваться?

Answer (score 0):

Примените метод `.reverse()`, который изменит порядок элементов списка *на месте,* т.е. после команды

```
y = [y for y in range(10,31) if prost(y) == 1]
```

добавите еще команду

```
y.reverse()
```

---

*Вывод:*

> ```
> [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
> [29, 23, 19, 17, 13, 11]
> ```

---

**Осторожно!**

Метод `.reverse()` возвращает `None`, а **не** новый список, потому **не работает ни**

```
y = [y for y in range(10,31) if prost(y) == 1].reverse()
```

**ни**

```
y = y.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

ну так сделайте так: `range(30, 10, -1)`

```
def prost(n):
    for i in range(2, int(n**.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return 0
    return 1

x = [x for x in range(10,31)]
y = [y for y in range(30, 10, -1) if prost(y) == 1]

print(x)
print(y)
```

кстати зачем вы множители до `n / 2` проверяете - это же избыточно и сложность O(n)

проверяйте до `sqrt(n)` - этого достаточно, чтобы понять, что число простое

**вариант 2:**

```
y = [y for y in range(10,31) if prost(y) == 1][::-1]
```

**вариант 3 (неоптимальный)**

```
y = [y for y in sorted(range(10,31), reverse=True) if prost(y) == 1]
```

или

```
y = sorted([y for y in range(10,31) if prost(y) == 1], reverse=True)
```